# PHP: Undefined offset 1 error

Tags: php, error-handling

I am trying to format number with k,m,b,t format after 1000, but I am getting this message:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

I can't understand what is wrong and how to solve the problem.

```
$x = round($num);
$x_number_format = number_format($x);
$x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);
$x_parts = array('k', 'm', 'b', 't');
$x_count_parts = count($x_array) - 1;
$x_display = $x;
$x_display = $x_array[0] . ((int) $x_array[1][0] !== 0 ? '.' . $x_array[1][0] : '');
$x_display .= $x_parts[$x_count_parts - 1];
return $x_display;
```

Here is the `var_dump()` result with `$x_array;` after explode..

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "1" }
```

Comment: This looks to me like the number is less than 1000

Comment: `$x_array` is a simple array; but you're using `$x_array[1][0]`, which will only work if it's a multi-dimensional one. I think you might need `$x_array[1]`?

Comment: do a `var_dump($x_array);` after define it (`$x_array = explode(',', $x_number_format);`) and update question with response?

Comment: okay let me check and get back to you.. thanks

Comment: @landons Oh I see that could be the problem as my number are still in 2 digits.. let me check by increasing the value.. BTW how can I ignore error if less than 10000?

Comment: @pixelngrain Either using conditions, or some `sprintf` magic.

Comment: @landons yeah I have checked and that is the exact problem. As I updated value to 1200 it works fine without error.. please guide me to ignore if less than 1000

Comment: @SamSullivan I have updated question with var_dump result please check..

Comment: @SamSullivan See my answer.  Also, what format are you trying to return?  There has to be a better way...

Answer (score 1):

Put this right after your first line:

```
if ($x < 1000) return $x;
```

**EDIT (simpler approach; entire function):**

```
if     ($x < 1000)    return round($x);
elseif ($x < 1000000) return round($x/1000)   .'k';
else                  return round($x/1000000).'m';
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying to return view count in 1k, 2k, 1m and so on format.. so if it is less than 1000 it will keep display as 999..

Comment: Thanks again but this is not giving any output.. don't know what I am doing wrong..

Comment: Yeah I did.. just tel me if I am wrong.. I have done with bit different approach. I am checking if $x_number_format has `,` than convert with `k,m` etc and if not than simple digit.. is it okay or bad coding?

Comment: @pixelngrain I think it's unnecessary complexity, personally

Comment: I see.. okay than I will paste code and I request your detailed guidance to solve this.. thanks a lot..